# iTunes Apple Music not starting a New Station from Artist/Album

Tags: itunes, apple-music

I, like others I've been seeing on Apple official support forums, am having issues to start a new Radio Station with Apple Music on my iTunes.

This feature works with almost no artist that I tried in my library. The issue only occurs on iTunes. All artists/albums I try to create a new Station from with my iPhone 6 work just fine.

Is there any way you guys can think of to "reset" something that may be getting this stuck? A cache or similar?

Thank you for your time!